# Dynamic JOptionPane.showMessageDialog in Swing

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

What would be the simplest way to create some sort of basic message box and refresh text on it?

Comment: *"and refresh text on it?"*  Do you mean change it while the option pane is still open?

Comment: Use a JLabel as the "message" component of a JOptionPane

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest dialog box you can create and display with the javax.swing.JOptionPane class is the message dialog box. This can be done with the static method: showMessageDialog(frame, message, title, type), where:

1. "frame" is a frame object to be used as the parent frame.
2. "message" is the message string to be display on the dialog box.
   3."title" is the title string to be used as the dialog box title.
3. "type" is an integer code representing a specific message dialog box type. Valid type codes are predefined as constants in the
   JOptionPane class: INFORMATION_MESSAGE, WARNING_MESSAGE,
   ERROR_MESSAGE and PLAIN_MESSAGE.

**Here is an example program**

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
public class JOptionPaneShowMessageDialog implements ActionListener {
   JFrame myFrame = null;
   public static void main(String[] a) {
      (new JOptionPaneShowMessageDialog()).test();
   }
   private void test() {
      myFrame = new JFrame("showMessageDialog Test");
      myFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      myFrame.setBounds(50,50,250,150);
      myFrame.setContentPane(new JDesktopPane());
      JMenuBar myMenuBar = new JMenuBar();
      JMenu myMenu = getDialogMenu();
      myMenuBar.add(myMenu);
      myFrame.setJMenuBar(myMenuBar);
      myFrame.setVisible(true);
   }
   private JMenu getDialogMenu() {
      JMenu myMenu = new JMenu("Dialogs");
      JMenuItem myItem = new JMenuItem("Information");
      myItem.addActionListener(this);
      myMenu.add(myItem);
      myItem = new JMenuItem("Warning");
      myItem.addActionListener(this);
      myMenu.add(myItem);
      myItem = new JMenuItem("Error");
      myItem.addActionListener(this);
      myMenu.add(myItem);
      myItem = new JMenuItem("Plain");
      myItem.addActionListener(this);
      myMenu.add(myItem);
      return myMenu;
   }
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      String menuText = ((JMenuItem) e.getSource()).getText();
      int messageType = JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE;
      if (menuText.equals("Information")) {
         messageType = JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE;
      } else if (menuText.equals("Warning")) {
         messageType = JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE;
      } else if (menuText.equals("Error")) {
         messageType = JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE;
      } else if (menuText.equals("Plain")) {
         messageType = JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE;
      }

      System.out.println("Before displaying the dialog: "+menuText);
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(myFrame, 
         "This is message dialog box of type: "+menuText,
         menuText+" Message", messageType);
      System.out.println("After displaying the dialog: "+menuText);
   }
}
```

Comment: What did you mean... you've asked a very ambigious question, and then ignored a request for clarification. If you make yourself hard to help then people will very quickly give-up on trying to help you, because they find it fustrating... it's human nature.